How do I get the price of BTC at midnight using coinbase
I have been searching and have not found a good solution. I'm trying to get coinbase's btc-usd price at midnight. The closest I have gotten successfully is calling by date but I cant get any closer than the day this way https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot?date=2024-05-07  I have attached my best attempt but that gives me a different number every time it is called.
import requests
from datetime import datetime


CRYPTO_PAIR = "BTC-USD"

now = datetime.now()
midnight = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
formatted_date = midnight.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
url = f"https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/{CRYPTO_PAIR}/spot"
response = requests.get(url, params={"date": formatted_date})
data = response.json()["data"]
price = data["amount"]
print(price)

I have also tried in a different way but this gives me the value 44,000 and something when it should be at a little above 63,000.
    midnight_timestamp = int(time.mktime(time.strptime('00:00:00:2024', '%H:%M:%S:%Y')))
    ohlcv = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, '1d', since=midnight_timestamp * 1000)
    midnight_price = ohlcv[0][4]  # Closing price at midnight
    return midnight_price



The format of the date parameter is strictly YYYY-MM-DD What you probably want is the price on the previous day to now()

in question (not in comments) you could add link to documentation.

documentation for prices shows examples for Python and you can see it uses special module coinbase - maybe you should also use it.

did you try with API KEY? Maybe without API KEY it send random data only for tests.

@furas the documentation states "No permission required" - i.e., no API Key needed although (I guess) it would be rate-limited

@SIGHUP I saw example in documentation client = Client(<api_key>, <api_secret>) and I assumed that it needs API key (like many other APIs) :) Maybe you are right that OP needs only now() - timedelta(days=1)

You can't get prices via this API with any finer granularity than 1 day.
At a guess, I'd suggest that if you get a price for the previous day (i.e., the day before you run your code) that would be the latest value on that day.
As stated in my comment, the date format for this API is strictly YYYY-MM-DD
I suggest that this might help:
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def yesterday():
    _yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    return str(_yesterday).split()[0]

params = {
    "date": yesterday()
}

url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot"

with requests.get(url, params=params) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    amount = float(response.json()["data"]["amount"])
    print(f"{amount:,.2f}")


When I run this code it gives me the value 63,161.35 but on coinbase it says the price at midnight for the 8th is 62,884.37

@kobis At the time of writing this comment, It is not midnight on 8th May anywhere in the world. So I have no idea what your point is. You will certainly need to review the API documentation because it seems that you don't understand how it's used

I mean 12am right after 11:59pm on the 7th on the eastern cost of the US.

@kobis Have you considered asking Coinbase why this is happening?
